# How do I add components to app UI in Android Studio Giraffe?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

I like to build iPhone apps in Xcode. I decided to expand to Android app dev. so I downloaded Android Studio Giraffe on my Windows 11 pc. I got on YouTube and the Internet to check out tutorials, but everywhere I go I get stuck on adding components (buttons, labels, etc.) to my UI. On my tutorials, they go to "activity_main.xml" file and go to the "Design" tab and under "Pallette" they can search for the components they want. My problem is I simply can't find my "activity_main.xml" file. Instead, I have a xml file called "AndroidManifest.xml" and I can't figure out how to add components to my UI. I noticed my default generated Kotlin code for an empty template looks different. Mine kind of reminds me of SwiftUI (example: Text( text = "Hello $name", modifier = modifier) I know it's out of context, but you get the point.) and I have a lot more than they do. My preview for my UI also looks different. Mine doesn't show the whole UI like theirs does, just a portion of it. My question is do I add components IN MY CODE similarly to SwiftUI (Like with buttons) ? Do we no longer do it manually by searching for them in the activity main xml file?

I'm having trouble getting answers. If someone could please answer my question and direct me to some kind of resource I would really apricate it. I'm new to this and would be grateful for some advice. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using XML files for designing UI and layouts is a legacy way that you can use (but not recommended, like storyboards in iOS).

Nowadays Android uses Jetpack Compose (which is similar to SwiftUI in iOS) it means you can make your UI in your Kotlin code.

Jetpack Compose is a library developed by Google and a lot of Android developers work with it.

Google has made a series of videos and articles that teach you how to use the latest technologies to build better apps, more quickly and easily. you can follow it [here](https://developer.android.com/series/mad-skills).

Comment: THANK YOU so much!! That was exactly what I was looking for! I appreciate you taking the time to answer! Take care!

Comment: @CoderGirl if you are satisfied with the answer please accept it.

Comment: @LawrenceGimenez thank you for telling me. I’m new around here and still figuring out how this works.

Comment: @CoderGirl all good, no problem.

Comment: Why did they deprecate the xml ui? I think it was great unlike iOS storyboards, which was a pain.

Comment: @DinuNicolae The xml UI has the potential to cause bugs in the application, for example suppose you use "findViewById" to get a particular view and the view has been removed already now an exception will be thrown.
Some attempts were made such as view binding but they need code generation.

In addition to this, nowadays, in most UI frameworks such as React JS, UI writing is done in a declarative form, where the state of the entire page is kept in a variable. Thus, by changing the value of the variables, we can verify that it is in sync with the reliable UI.